# Python - Assign Variable to Function/Call

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to assign a variable to a function call that simply capitalizes several paragraphs I got in a file, but the function call itself doesn't let me assign the variable, the error is `Can't assign to function call`

```
def text():
    with open("par.txt", "r") as pa:
    lines = pa.read()

    context=lines.split("/n")
    str_para=''.join(context)
    x=str_para.split('\n')

    for i in range(len(x)):
        words =''.join(x[i]).capitalize(),end='\n'
    return words

texts()
```

when I only use `print(''.join(x[i]).capitalize(),end='\n')`, it works fine, but i get the error once i assign the variable, how could i make this work?

Comment: What do you expect the `,end='\n\n\n'` to do? I think that's just leftover from the call to `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.
Are you aware there is an indentation missing below the with statement? Might just be a formatting error of SO.

Try if that does what you want:

```
words = ''
for i in range(len(x)):
    words +=''.join(x[i]).capitalize() + '\n\n\n'
return words
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the end parameter for the print statement. You need to also concatenate that. I adapted my example.